# adaptor/method to connect to the mainframe api in node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mainframe, cics

I need to access a mainframe API from a webpage/browser. 
The mainframe API is accessible to the webserver but not exposed to the web.

The API is returning 40000 bytes of data per packet, it is using the CICS.LU6.2 protocol.

I am planning to develop a node.js server on linux to expose the mainframe API to the web, i.e. making this a "web API", so that it can be used with angular.js to develop a website.

I did not find any adaptor/method to connect to the mainframe API in node.js.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your own understanding of what LU 6.2 is, and then explain how you think it would help do what you want? Why don't you talk to the CICS support people at your site. You need to make a website, it needs to communicate with CICS, how should you do this with your site's installed software (or newly licensed parts if necessary/authorised) and with your site's security policies. I don't think LU 6.2 will be part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, trying to digging out the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need to retain an existing API flowing over LU 6.2, then you'll need some sort of gateway that can transform your web requests (most likely HTTP) to SNA LU 6.2. While you can write this yourself, there are several commercial products that can do some or all of this work for you.

[One IBM solution is described here.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/DoMoreWithTXSeries/entry/txseries_can_transform_lu6_2_to_http_xml?lang=en)

There are also solutions from third-party vendors like CA - [here's a link to the CA API Management product](https://www.ca.com/us/products/ca-api-gateway.html). The third-party solutions often have other features that might be important to you, such as security and load-balancing or fault-tolerance.

Given that you're open to a Linux solution, you can also achieve something similar to CA's API Management solution using open-source technologies, such as the WSO2 stack or the Mule ESB. These are big decisions that go way beyond just bridging LU 6.2 to HTTP, but most of what you need can be done for free.

Your site very likely has a strategy for API management - if so, you should definitely figure out what your site standards are. Security and lots of other issues are difficult to get exactly right, so you'll want to be careful if this is your organization's first taste of exposing existing services to the web.

Comment: Thanks a ton to giving a direction to me, ws02 and mule ESB needs to looked on.